# if else structure in java printing out strange code

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

Hi there I have become stuck with an exercise on if-else statements in java the problem is when I run the code it prints;
Enter a card: 9 S
end
9ofS

please see below for my code example:

```
 String suit;
 String rank;
 String userOne; 
 Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
 System.out.print("Enter a card: ");
 rank= sc.next(); 
 suit= sc.next();
 userOne= sc.next();
 if (userOne.equals("9")){
   System.out.println("Nine");
 } else if (userOne.equals("S")){
   System.out.println("Spades");       
 }
 System.out.print(rank+ "of" +suit);
```

had to squeeze the code in at the bottom I know its not in the right format but for just getting an answer to this question I had to lay it out like that.

Why is the code printing out-

```
Enter a card: 9 S
end
9ofS
```

instead of

```
Enter a card: 9 S
Nine of Spades ?
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect it to print what you expect. Can I suggest you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Think carefully about the possible values of `userOne` as compared to the values of `rank` and `suit`.

Comment: You are waiting for 3 inputs, which it appears you only want two. And you are printing the user inputs in your final print statement, and has nothing to do with your if else statements.

Comment: When you type "end", your userOne variable is assigned to string "end". That's why your if-else condition can't be matched and your code falls through to "System.out.print" directly. You are waiting for three inputs, be careful.

Comment: Thank you for your responses I can now see where I went wrong in the piece of code I submitted to you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you said it to do. What I understand you want something like this below :

```
String suit;
         String rank;
         String userOne; 
         Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
         System.out.print("Enter a card: ");
         rank= sc.next(); 
         suit= sc.next();
         userOne= sc.next();
         if (userOne.equals("9")){
           System.out.println("Nine");
    String nine = "Nine" ;
         } else if (userOne.equals("S")){
           System.out.println("Spades"); 
    String spades = "Spades";      
         }
         System.out.print(nine+ " of " +spades);
```

Comment: nine and spade variables are out of scope.